# Datatables server-side not sorting text with numbers properly

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm having some difficulty handling the sorting of data that has both text and numeric.  I'm using datatables serverside plug-in and I'm trying to include the natural-sort plugin.

I have a column that has data like this:

```
Unit #1
Unit #10
Unit #2
```

When I sort on the column it sorts, but the ordering is not how I want it to display.  This is what I need:

```
Unit #1    
Unit #2
Unit #10
```

I saw some other posts where people used the "natural-sort" plugin found here: [datatables natural sort](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting)

I put the javascript into a main.js file for the natural-sort function.

This is how I initialize the dataTable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    var oTable = $("table.datatable_ss_1348508281").dataTable( {

        "oLanguage": {"sSearch": "Search these results:"},
        "aLengthMenu": [[10,20,50,100,500,1000], [10,20,50,100,500,1000]],          
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "includes/units_dropdown_dt_process.php?id=1532&cont_id=unit_id",
         "fnDrawCallback": function() {
                                //$('span.paginate_active').trigger('click');
                            },      
        "aoColumnDefs":[],
        "aoColumns": [{"sType": "natural"}, null, null],
        "aaSorting": [[ 0,"asc" ]],
        "sScrollY": "300px",

            } ).fnSetFilteringDelay(500);

    jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "natural-asc": function ( a, b ) {
            return naturalSort(a,b);
        },

        "natural-desc": function ( a, b ) {
            return naturalSort(a,b) * -1;
        }
    } );

</script>
```

The problem is it still sorts using text and doesn't factor in the numbers...Any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

my understand  that i saw somewhere is you have to replace the text with a numerical value, Unit #1 becomes 1